# Side effect/ changing global varaibles that pass into a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables, variable-assignment

Forgive me if this question has been asked, but I can't seem to find it.

I am attempting to create an array and reverse it (without using reverse)
This bit of code works perfect:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}


var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

As you can see, it takes an in an `array`, does some logic, and returns the same altered `array`.

Although, it doesn't make sense to me why this code doesn't work:

```
var some_array = [6,7,8,9,10];

function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    var replacement_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++)
        replacement_array.unshift(array[i])
    array = replacement_array;
    return array;
}

reverseArrayInPlace(some_array);
console.log(some_array);
// → [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

This code also takes in an array, does some logic (and assignment) and returns an array back. Why doesn't it alter the global variable like the first one? Is there any way to change it so that it can?

Comment: Because you are creating an new array, that's what `replacement_array=[]` does. Note that everything is passed by value in JS. Also, `replacement_array` is missing `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,you need this:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
   replacement_array = [];
   for (var i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
   { 
       replacement_array.unshift(array[i])

   }
   for(var i = 0; i <array.length; i++){
       array[i]=replacement_array[i]
   }
   return array;
}
some_array = [6,7,8,9,10];
reverseArrayInPlace(some_array)
console.log(some_array)
```

Replace the variable's content will work.

Comment: Thanks, after realizing that I had to change the variable's content, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To affect the global directly:

```js
    var some_array = [6,7,8,9,10];
    
    function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
        var replacement_array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            replacement_array.unshift(array[i]);
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = replacement_array[i];
    }
     
    reverseArrayInPlace(some_array);
    alert(some_array);
```

You don't need to return array.

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do. I would like the code to be able to handle any global array, not just a hardcoded one.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Is this what you were after?

Comment: Not quite, I would like to simply call `reverseArrayInPlace(some_array);` and have the global be updated (like how it is done in the first example). Is that possible?

Comment: You have to replace the contents of the variable. The `array` argument is not a strict reference to the array outside, it is a new value, that happens to hold a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through the code:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    var replacement_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++)
        replacement_array.unshift(array[i])
```

At this point you have created a new array that's the reverse of the original array.

```
    array = replacement_array;
```

Assigning a new value to `array` will not alter the original array; only mutable array methods or element dereferencing can effect that.

```
    return array;
}
```

You're returning the new array here, so you can perform an assignment outside of the function:

```
some_array = reverseArrayInPlace(some_array);
console.log(some_array);
```

However, that no longer qualifies as modifying an array in-place; you can use `unshift()` and `splice()` though:

```
for (var i = 1, n = array.length; i < n; ++i) {
    array.unshift(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down, this made it much more clear as to why assignment wasn't working. I was however looking for modifying the array in place, could you perhaps give an example of the best way to do that?

Comment: @ApathyBear Well, I've given an alternative; not sure how well it performs, but if you want performant code you should have used `reverse()` =p